# Showing error while adding 4 menu (items) in BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, xml, bottomnavigationview

I am new to android .. trying to build application that is having webview inside fragment and in the bottom it is having BottomNavigationView on click of particular item fragment change according to click .

every thing is working fine when having 3 items in BottomNavigationView when i add 4 app start crashing .

error is as fallows -

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: in.xparticle.digitalkabadi, PID: 23369
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.xparticle.digitalkabadi/in.xparticle.digitalkabadi.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19 in in.xparticle.digitalkabadi:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #19 in in.xparticle.digitalkabadi:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:491)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:940)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19 in in.xparticle.digitalkabadi:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #19 in in.xparticle.digitalkabadi:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19 in in.xparticle.digitalkabadi:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at in.xparticle.digitalkabadi.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7824)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7813)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:491)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:940)
E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setImportantForAccessibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setImportantForAccessibility(ViewCompat.java:1119)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationItemView.<init>(BottomNavigationItemView.java:104)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationItemView.<init>(BottomNavigationItemView.java:87)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationItemView.<init>(BottomNavigationItemView.java:83)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenuView.getNewItem(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:606)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenuView.buildMenuView(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:538)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationPresenter.updateMenuView(BottomNavigationPresenter.java:67)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.inflateMenu(BottomNavigationView.java:344)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:226)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:133)
            ... 28 more
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new HomeFragment()).commit();
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                    switch (item.getItemId()){
                        case R.id.nav_home:
                            selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_scrape_price:
                            selectedFragment = new ScrapePriceFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_aboutUs:
                            selectedFragment = new AboutUsFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_scrape_Process:
                            selectedFragment = new AboutUsFragment();
                            break;

                    }
                    assert selectedFragment != null;
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            selectedFragment).commit();
                    return true;
                }

            };
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this -->

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //loading the default fragment
    loadFragment(new FirstFragment());

    //getting bottom navigation view and attaching the listener
    BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}


@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.id1:
            fragment = new FirstFragment();
            break;

        case R.id.id2:
            fragment = new SecondFragment();
            break;

        case R.id.id3:
            fragment = new thirsFragment();
            break;

        case R.id.id4:
            fragment = new fourthFragment();
            break;
    }

    return loadFragment(fragment);
}

private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    //switching fragment
    if (fragment != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .commit();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}